# How does AWS Neptune fts.maxResults affect the search results?

Tags: amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

When I set the maxResults to 100, I get 20 results.

When I set the maxResults to 10,  I get 1 result.

[From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-parameters.html):
`maxResults   –   The maximum number of results to return. The default is the index.max_result_window OpenSearch setting, which itself defaults to 1000. The maxResults parameter can specify any number lower than that.`

From this description, I would expect to get 10 results from setting maxResults to 10, but I only get 1. When I set it to 12, I get 2 results. There is obviously something that maxResults is doing here that I don't understand.

```
limit = 100
g.withSideEffect(
    "Neptune#fts.endpoint", f"{url}"
)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.queryType", "query_string")
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.maxResults", limit)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#enableResultCache", enable_cache)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.sortOrder", "DESC")
.V()
.hasLabel("table")
.has(
    "*",
    f"Neptune#fts entity_type:"table" AND ({query})",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason behind this behaviour was the cache. Invalidating it before running the query seems to result in the expected behaviour stated. I'm still unclear why this is the case though.